# Render a partial template with passed parameters

Tags: go, go-templates

I know rendering a partial template with additional parameters is possible in Ruby, how can I do it in Go?

I have a partial template `_partial1.tmpl`:

```
<div>
text1
{{if foo}}
   text2
{{end}}
</div>
```

using it from the parent template `parent.tmpl`:

```
<div>
  {{ template "partial1",  }} // how do I pass foo param here?? 
</div>
```

How do I pass the parameter `foo` to the partial?

Answer (score 5):

The [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) states that the `template` directive has two forms:

> `{{template "name"}}`
>   The template with the specified name is executed
>   with nil data.
>
> **`{{template "name" pipeline}}`**
>   The template with the specified name is
>   **executed with dot set to the value of the pipeline.**

The latter accepts a pipeline statement which's value is then set to the `dot` value in the executed template. So calling

```
{{template "partial1" "string1"}}
```

will set `{{.}}` to `"string1"` in the `partial1` template. So while there is no way to set the name `foo` in the partial, you can pass parameters and they will appear in `.`. Example:

#### template.html

```
<div>
  {{ template "partial1.html" "muh"}} // how do I pass foo param here??
</div>
```

#### partial1.html

```
{{if eq . "muh"}}
blep
{{else}}
moep
{{end}}
```

#### main.go

```
import (
    "html/template"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    t,err := template.ParseFiles("template.html", "partial1.html")

    if err != nil { panic(err) }

    fmt.Println(t.Execute(os.Stdout, nil))
}
```

Running this program will print the template's contents with `blep` from the partial. Changing the passed value will change this behaviour.

You can also assign variables, so assigning `.` to `foo` is possible in the partial:

```
{{ $foo := . }}
```